# Android: use of any inputType stops the ability to select autoCompleteTextView list items

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-inputtype

I am having issues that setting an inputType interfering with the ability to select items from the list for an AutoCompleteTextView.  I am setting the inputType in the styles.xml but even if the style it is set in is not used either directly or as a parent of the AutoCompleteTextView it causes an issue whereby the selections from the adapter are displayed but the user cannot select them.

If I remove the inputType the AutoCompleteTextView list selection works as expected.

Can anyone explain what is causing this behaviour and is there a (simple) way to fix it?  I would like to keep the style definition central rather than setting in each EditText for example.  Do I need to handle the list selection in code to overcome this?

Comment: `"... but the user cannot select them."`, what do you mean? `OnItemSelectedListener#onItemSelected` is not called?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I mean if a user selects an item in the list nothing happens.  Without any inputType set anywhere in my project if the user selects an item in the list that item populates the AutoCompleteTextView box and the list closes (the behaviour I would expect).  I have not implemented those methods so can't tell if they are not called but would assume that they are not.